# Why Coupon code is not applied to cart programmatically?

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, shopping-cart-price-rules, promotions, coupon-codes

I tried to generate coupon and apply to cart programmatically. With the following script coupon generate successfully but its not applied to cart, Even if tried to apply manually. If I just save this coupon code without any changes in admin panel and then applied to cart its works. I think I am missing something here. (I got this code from [here](http://inchoo.net/magento/programming-magento/programmatically-create-apply-and-delete-shopping-cart-price-rule-in-magento/))

```
$coupon_code = Mage::helper('core')->getRandomString(16);
$frm_date = Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('Y-m-d');
$to_date = date( "Y-m-d", strtotime( "+2 day", strtotime($frm_date) ) );
$data = array(
'product_ids' => null,
'name' => 'AUTO_GENERATION_Coupon',
'description' => null,
'is_active' => 1,
'website_ids' => array(1),
'customer_group_ids' => array(0,1),
'coupon_type' => 2,
'coupon_code' => $coupon_code,
'uses_per_coupon' => 1,
'uses_per_customer' => 1,
'from_date' => $frm_date,
'to_date' => $to_date,
'sort_order' => 100,
'is_advanced' => 1,
'is_rss' => 0,
'conditions' => array(
    '1'=> array(
        'type' => 'salesrule/rule_condition_combine',
        'aggregator' => 'all',
        'value' => 1,
        'new_child' => null
    ),
    '1--1' => array(
        'type' => 'salesrule/rule_condition_address',
        'attribute' => 'base_subtotal_with_discount_without_points',
        'operator' => '>=',
'value' => 100
    )
),
'simple_action' => 'by_percent',
'discount_amount' => $percent_offer,
'discount_qty' => 0,
'discount_step' => 0,
'apply_to_shipping' => 0,
'simple_free_shipping' => 0,
'stop_rules_processing' => 1,
'store_labels' => array('0' => "$percent_offer% Cart below value discount", '1' => "$percent_offer% Cart below value discount")
);
$model = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule');
$data = $this->_filterDates($data, array('from_date', 'to_date'));
$validateResult = $model->validateData(new Varien_Object($data));
if ($validateResult == true) {

if (isset($data['simple_action']) && $data['simple_action'] == 'by_percent'
        && isset($data['discount_amount'])) {
    $data['discount_amount'] = min(100, $data['discount_amount']);
}

if (isset($data['rule']['conditions'])) {
    $data['conditions'] = $data['rule']['conditions'];
}

if (isset($data['rule']['actions'])) {
    $data['actions'] = $data['rule']['actions'];
}

unset($data['rule']);

$model->loadPost($data);

$model->save();

Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')
->getQuote()
->setCouponCode(strlen($coupon_code) ? $coupon_code: '')
->collectTotals()
->save();
}
```

Please tell me what is missing?

Comment: Where is `$couponCode` defined in your code? `->setCouponCode(strlen($couponCode) ? $couponCode : '')` seem to be alway null

Comment: @R.S  At very first line of code. its just simple random string. I edited question. its $coupon_code. (its copy paste mistake)

Comment: have you checked this  coupon is applied manually properly

Comment: yes I tried several times. its only works if I just save it from admin panel nothing else.

Comment: can put code of _filterDates()

Comment: @ganesh Is your issue creating the coupon code (and not really adding it to cart)?

Comment: @R.S Yes it generate proper coupon code. but not applied to cart.

Comment: @AmitBera I am using core function `_filterDates()`, its not modified.

Comment: Why did you change the `conditions` section in data (by leaving out `rule`) from array `'is_rss' => 0,
'conditions' => array(
`'is_rss' => 1,
    'rule' => array(
        'conditions' => array(`

Comment: if `conditions` mentioned inside `'rule' => array(` its do not create conditions. As per `http://marius-strajeru.blogspot.in/2010/04/create-bulk-discount-rules.html` it works with direct `conditions` array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whats wrong with code is wrong date format for `from_date` and `to_date`.
Date format worked for me is `'n/j/y'`, this is same date format, I found in 'shopping cart price rule` admin panel page.

Hope this will help someone.